# 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-core, timespan

I am trying to get "ago" time within C# but am currently struggling as I get this Error.

Basically this is what I am trying.

```
var dateAgo = $"{DateTime.Now.Subtract(booking.CreatedAt.Date)}";
```

`booking.createdAt.Date` is where my date for my booking is saved.
I can show `@dateAgo` in my HTML but the problem is when I try something like

```
@DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(booking.CreatedAt.Date).ToString("d")
```

which sadly does not work.

Comment: What is the type of `booking.CreatedAt.Date`?  From the error, I'd guess it's not a `DateTime` hence the error

Comment: "I get this Error" - It would help to let us know **which** error

Comment: @Martin @booking.CreatedAt.Date.GetType() gives me System.DateTime

Comment: @PeterB "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'"

Comment: @ebrowkin Try the `ToString()` call without the `"d"` parameter and then try changing `"d"` to `"%d"`

Comment: @ebrowkin You can encourage helpful answerers by upvoting their answers by clicking on the up arrow to the left of their answers. Also, you can mark one of the answers as accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Subtract()` yields a `TimeSpan` object. `ToString("d")` is not a standard `TimeSpan` format string. See [Standard `TimeSpan` Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings).

You want the **custom** format string [`"d"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#dSpecifier) which outputs the number of days. For this, change `"d"` to `"%d"`:

```
@DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(booking.CreatedAt.Date).ToString("%d")
```

Or you can simply extract the `Days` from the returned `TimeSpan` object which will return the number of days:

```
@DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(booking.CreatedAt.Date).Days.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.Now.Subtract(booking.CreatedAt.Date).Days`

Answer (score 1):

`Subtract()` produces a **`TimeSpan`**, which is [incompatible with using the "d" format specifier by itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings). Try something else, e.g. `.ToString("%d")` or `.ToString("c")`.

Or if needed, the TimeSpan provides `.Days`, `.Hours` etc properties which can be used instead.